# How to display popup alert in Java from excel sheet where the (Date) value is null?

Tags: java

In my excel sheet I have data columns like `date`, `name`, `sno`. I am getting data from excel sheet to Java and it is working well. But when the `date` column is null in the sheet I get error showing popup like date column is null.

```
String excellDate = "";
try {
    System.out.println(row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue());
    excellDate = String.valueOf(row.getCell(3).getDateCellValue()).toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("invalid start date" + patient.getPname());
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Warning!");
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // to show top of all other application
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly happens when the date is null? You don't see the popup at all? Are there any messages in the log? Is there any exception?

Comment: I see no nullcheck here

Comment: You should probably use, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "invalid start date" + patient.Pname(), "Warning!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE)`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at task5.task5.ExcelReader.convertExcellTopatient(ExcelReader.java:78)
 at task5.task5.Task1.main(Task1.java:25)

Comment: I am getting error as I mentioned above, but I want popup alert like, start date is null

Comment: I am fetching value from excel sheet where start date is blank

Comment: Is "Task1.java:25" in your try block? What is line 25 of Task1.java? Also, you don't need "toString" after you call "String.valueOf", that returns a string.